# Lua - rearrange a string in alphabetical order

Tags: lua

I'm new to lua and I'm trying to figure out how to rearrange a string in alphabetical order. For example if the string is "APPLE", then my code should return "AELPP". How can I achieve this? Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! See also: [ask]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```lua
   local function sort(input)
      local buffer = {}
      for i=1,#subject do
         buffer[i] = subject:sub(i,i)
      end
      table.sort(buffer)
      return table.concat(buffer)
   end

   print(sort("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet"))
```

It's not the most "elegant" solution, but benchmarking on Lua 5.3 it's certainly the fastest one when compared to looping with `gmatch` and `gsub`.

```
gsub    took 0.278914 seconds
gmatch  took 0.260757 seconds
numfor  took 0.228867 seconds
```

For LuaJIT 2.1 the result is very similar:

```
gsub    took 0.167457 seconds
gmatch  took 0.157505 seconds
numfor  took 0.124351 seconds
```

Benchmark details: 100 repetitions of the full function called on a string of length 4300 characters. All functions share the common overhead of sorting and concatenating, so the performance difference of the loop constructs alone is larger than what the numbers show.

Comment: Just for curiosity, could you please add `local buf = {str:byte(1, str:len())} table.sort(buf) return string.char(table.unpack(buf))` to the benchmark?

Comment: @Green Not anymore; I already closed that editor and it wasn't saved anywhere ;P It shouldn't be too hard to recreate the benchmark though, if you're curious enough and want to try.

Comment: Cheers, no worries. I just hoped that you still have it laying around. I'll give it a shot after work.

Answer (score 2):

You should:

1. Change string to char table
2. Sort table
3. Change table to string

For example:

```
local str = "APPLE"
local tab = {}
str:gsub(".",function(c) table.insert(tab,c) end)
table.sort(tab)
str = table.concat(tab)
print(str)
```